# Mudar texto de botão "Previous" e "Next" em Datatables - TableTools

Tags: jquery-datatables

Alguém sabe como alterar o texto dos botões default "Previous" e "Next" no datatables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que li na [documentação](https://datatables.net/reference/option/):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "paginate": {
      "previous": "Anterior",
      "next": "Próximo"
    }
  }
} );
```

Fontes [aqui](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.paginate.previous) e  [aqui](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.paginate.next)